# Countrywise mobile number validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, package

I want to validate mobile number depending on selected country.

Is there any Angular package for this.

I have tried regex but its for specific countries. i want to validate all countries mobile and landline numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are comfortable with adopting to a jquery based solution, you can very well try the `formvalidation` jquery plugin which has support to validate your international phone numbers,

Detailed documentation with demo is available at,

http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-international-phone-numbers/

Hope this helps